# Washing vegetables that I accidentally threw moldy tomato sauce on safe?

Tags: food-safety, sauce, tomatoes, mushrooms, mold

So I was frying some mushrooms and was gonna put tomato sauce/passata on it but I didn't realize it was moldy until I squeezed it out of the box and onto the mushrooms. I immediately put everything in a strainer and washed the mushrooms with hot water and then continued to cook them and put fresh sauce on them but I'm not sure it's safe to eat? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Washing the vegetables properly after getting the moldy sauce on them, and cooking them properly after should be fine. Your body is pretty well equipped to fight off small traces of most molds, you will only get sick if you ingest a substantial amount of mold.